# unable to install pi-hole from AUR on Arch ARM

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, aur, pi-hole

I'm running Arch ARM on my RasPi and wanted to install pi-hole. I found https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pi-hole-server/ in the AUR, cloned it requires a few dependecies it cannot install by itself. Fine, I found and installed:

- `net-tools`
- `logrotate`
- `fakeroot`
- `bind-tools`
- `strip`

in the regular arch repositories with `pacman` but `pi-hole-ftl` is to be installed from `AUR` too. So I cloned the repo and executed `makepkg -si` upon which I got

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
```

fine, I was able to `export CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/cmake` which seemed to have helped with that but I also got:

```
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

and `export CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc` did not solve the issue. Why is this? How do I get this resolved?

I have:

```
 $ echo $CMAKE_C_COMPILER
 /usr/bin/gcc
```

`base-delvel` is already installed, I'm getting:

```
warning: autoconf-2.69-7 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: automake-1.16.2-3 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: binutils-2.34-5 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: bison-3.6.4-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: fakeroot-1.24-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: file-5.39-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: findutils-4.7.0-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: flex-2.6.4-3 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: gawk-5.1.0-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: gcc-10.1.0-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: gettext-0.20.2-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: grep-3.4-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: groff-1.22.4-3 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: gzip-1.10-3 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: libtool-2.4.6+42+gb88cebd5-13 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: m4-1.4.18-3 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: make-4.3-3 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: pacman-5.2.2-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: patch-2.7.6-8 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: pkgconf-1.7.3-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: sed-4.8-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: sudo-1.9.2-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: texinfo-6.7-3 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: which-2.21-5 is up to date -- reinstalling
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up cloning `yay` from the AUR, installing it with `makepkg -si` (also needed to `pacman -S make`)and then used yay to install `pi-hole-server` which worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

You should install `base-devel` if you want to build anything from the  AUR, because most packages assume everything from this group is already installed and don't add it as dependencies

Comment: `base-devel` is already installed, please see above